# Django admin remove m2m inlines?

Tags: django, admin, django-grappelli

I am using the Django admin with the Grappelli app to manage an M2M relationship (Gallery - Image) with an intermediary model with inline form sections.

I've added a gallery record with multiple images successfully, however when I go back and edit the record, I cannot remove any of the inline images.

The only way I have managed to remove the relationship is by deleting the image record separately.

Simply emptying the fields and saving throws up validation errors (ie This field is required etc). All I want to do is remove one or more inline form sections in its entirety.

Can anyone help?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Guess it would make sense to post the error message ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a checkbox for each inline to delete it.

If you can't see the delete checkboxes, then perhaps your user does not have the permission to delete the intermediary model.

Comment: I'm using the Grappelli app and each inline had an X in the right hand corner. I was expecting it to disappear when I clicked the X but this is actually still just a checkbox.